# Getting a null Property in MVVM pattern after replacing proprieties with a object containing them

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin.Forms with MVVM Pattern. What I'm trying to do right here is fetch text(email, password, confirm password) from the user and send it to the viewmodel.
Now I've already a 'RegisterBindingModel.cs' Class which have these three properties

So instead of this code in the View Model

```
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

I've used this code

```
public RegisterBindingModel RegisterBindingModel { get; set; }
```

**But i get a null RegisterBindingModel while debugging after this edit.**

The xaml page content 
And the Line `BindingContext="{Binding RegisterBindingModel}` was removed from the stacklayout tag

```
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Register Now! "/>
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{Binding RegisterBindingModel}">
            <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding ConfirmPassword}" IsPassword="True" Placeholder="ConfirmPassword" />
            </StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Register" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
```

And in the Registerpage.xaml.cs I've used this line of code:

```
  BindingContext = new RegisterViewModel(Navigation);
```

and the RegisterBindingModel class:

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

The Requested Edit

```
        private async void Register()
    {
        var isSuccess = await _identityService.RegisterAsync(RegisterBindingModel);
    }
```

So what went wrong after I've changed the code ?

Comment: Please extend the code fragments to a more complete context. f.i. Where exactly did you use the line of code `BindingContext = new RegisterViewModel(Navigation);`? Show us the definition of `RegisterViewModel`. Where did you assign a value to the `RegisterBindingModel` property?

Comment: Pre-initialize your _RegisterBindingModel_ property with a (empty) RegisterBindingModel object. (Just having a BindingContext bound to the property will not automatically cause the creation of a RegisterBindingModel object; think of simple bindings - without converters - just as assigning some UI element property to a ViewModel property or vice versa; there is no other stuff like object instantiations going on...)

Comment: @elgonzo can you show me how please ?

Comment: @SirRufo i've used the first line in RegisterPage.xaml.cs under the IntiliazeComponent();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first let's update your RegisterBindingModel. we need to add private fields where the data will be stored. The public properties you are using for binding will be setting/getting this data. The reason we want to do this in MVVM is so we can take advantage of two-way binding. In the future if you want to set the values of these fields to something and have the view update. This will be helpful. it will also help consolidate your update binding code to property setters.

```
public class RegisterBindingModel : BindableBase
{
    private string _email;
    public string Email { 
        get{
            return this._email;
        }
        set{
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._email, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _password;
    public string Password {
        get{
            return this._password;
        }
        set{
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._password, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private string _confirmPassword;
    public string ConfirmPassword {
        get{
            return this._confirmPassword;
        }
        set{
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) )
            {
                SetProperty(ref this._confirmPassword, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, Have you decided if you are going to use a MVVM framework (i.e. PRISM, MVVMCross, etc.) there are lots out there. It depends on personal perference. I am partial to PRISM. Prism has a ViewmodelBase and BindableBase class you can extend for your view model(s). It already implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

As elgonzo mention, update your RegisterViewModel.

```
public class RegisterViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private RegisterBindingModel _registerBindingModel;
    public RegisterBindingModel RegisterBindingModel 
    {
        get
        {
            return this._registerBindingModel;
        }
        set{
            SetProperty(ref this._registerBindingModel, value);
        }
    }

    public RegisterViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        //...
        this.RegisterBindingModel = new RegisterBindingModel();
    }
}
```